# Why is this XML Validation failing on NameIDFormat from an extended type?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saml, xsd-validation

I recently encountered an issue with SAML metadata validation from a customer.

The relevant part of metadata that is failing:

```
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0 urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

  <Extensions>
    <shibmd:Scope regexp="false">...</shibmd:Scope>
  </Extensions>

  <KeyDescriptor>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>
        ...
        </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </KeyDescriptor>
    
  <ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding" Location="..." index="1"/>
  <ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="..." index="2"/>

  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="h..."/>
    
  <NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat>
  <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
```

This fails with the folowing error:
`cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'NameIDFormat'. One of '{"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":SingleSignOnService, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":NameIDMappingService, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":AssertionIDRequestService, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":AttributeProfile, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":Attribute}' is expected.`

The following is the relevant portion of `saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd`:

```
<complexType name="SSODescriptorType" abstract="true">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="md:RoleDescriptorType">
      <sequence>
        <element ref="md:ArtifactResolutionService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:SingleLogoutService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:ManageNameIDService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:NameIDFormat" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="ArtifactResolutionService" type="md:IndexedEndpointType"/>
<element name="SingleLogoutService" type="md:EndpointType"/>
<element name="ManageNameIDService" type="md:EndpointType"/>
<element name="NameIDFormat" type="anyURI"/>

<element name="IDPSSODescriptor" type="md:IDPSSODescriptorType"/>
<complexType name="IDPSSODescriptorType">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="md:SSODescriptorType">
      <sequence>
        <element ref="md:SingleSignOnService" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:NameIDMappingService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:AssertionIDRequestService" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="md:AttributeProfile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="saml:Attribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </sequence>
      <attribute name="WantAuthnRequestsSigned" type="boolean" use="optional"/>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="SingleSignOnService" type="md:EndpointType"/>
<element name="NameIDMappingService" type="md:EndpointType"/>
<element name="AssertionIDRequestService" type="md:EndpointType"/>
<element name="AttributeProfile" type="anyURI"/>
```

I notice that the error message only specifies elements from the `IDPSSODescriptorType` and not the base `SSODescriptorType`. Maybe that's by design?

Regardless, I receive no errors for `ArtifactResolutionService` which also happens to be define in the base type.

In fact, if I move `<element ref="md:NameIDFormat" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>` in the schema file from the base `SSODescriptorType` to the `IDPSSODescriptorType`, and leave everything else, the metadata file passes validation.

I'm using Java 8 with the default implementation of `javax.xml.validation.*`

```
private static String[] schemas = {
  "/schema/xml.xsd",
  "/schema/XMLSchema.xsd",
  "/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd",
  "/schema/xenc-schema.xsd",
  "/schema/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd",
  "/schema/saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd",
};

public boolean validateXMLSchema(Document document) {
  try {
    SchemaFactory factory =
      SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(getSources().toArray(new Source[0]));

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
    return true;
  } catch (SAXException e) {
    log.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    log.debug("Exception: ", ex);
  }

  return false;
}
```

At this point I'm unsure what would be causing the `NameIDFormat` element to fail validation, or why the validator isn't finding it in the base type but does seem to find `ArtifactResolutionService`.

Comment: There's a second `NameIDFormar` element: `<element name="NameIDFormat" type="anyURI"/>`, may be that's confusing the validator.

Comment: How this element is produced it is generated without its minoccurs attribute while other elements of the same set type do have it.   , so  there is a malformation much as the parser error says.   <element  ref="md:SingleSignOnService"      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

Comment: @LMC I believe that element is the defininition and the other is a reference to it via `ref="md:NameIDFormat"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's going on. The customer metadata is indeed invalid (according to this schema).

The `complexType`s in the schema are specifying `sequence`s. This means the elements MUST be specified in that particular order.

According to the schema, the `NameIDFormat` elements defined in the `SSODescriptorType` must be specified before any of the elements defined by the `IDPSSODescriptorType`. Changing the metadata to the following works:

```
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0 urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

  <Extensions>
    <shibmd:Scope regexp="false">...</shibmd:Scope>
  </Extensions>

  <KeyDescriptor>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>
        ...
        </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </KeyDescriptor>

  <ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding" Location="..." index="1"/>
  <ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="..." index="2"/>

  <NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat>
  <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>

  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="..."/>
  <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="h..."/>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
```

Now to figure out how I'm going to handle this since it's unlikely I'll be able to get the customer to fix their metadata...

Answer (score 0):

How this element is produced it is generated without its minOccurs= attribute while other elements of the same set type do have it.   , so  there is a malformation much as the parser error says.

```
<element  ref="md:SingleSignOnService" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```